# Line not prompting for input

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to programming and have been working on an assignment in class. For some strange reason the program keeps printing 2 different printf's on the same line and not giving me a chance to input information

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{   char Name[20];
    char cid1[6]="", cid2[6]="", cid3[6]="", cid4[6]="", cid5[6]="", cid6[6]="";
    char Description1[21]="", Description2[21]="", Description3[21]="", Description4[21]="", Description5[21]="", Description6[21]="";
int hrs1 = 0, hrs2=0, hrs3=0, hrs4=0, hrs5=0, hrs6=0;
char grade1[2]="",grade2[2]="",grade3[2]="",grade4[2]="",grade5[2]="",grade6[2]="";

printf("Enter Students Name ");
fgets(Name, 20, stdin);

printf("Enter Class ID ");
scanf("%5s", cid1);

printf("Enter Class Description ");             // Problem
fgets(Description1, 20, stdin);                 // here

printf("Enter Class Hours ");
scanf("%d", &hrs1);

printf("Enter Class Grade ");
fgets(grade1, 1, stdin);

printf("%s\n", Name);
printf("%s\n", cid1);
printf("%s\n", Description1);
printf("%d\n", hrs1);
printf("%s\n", grade1);

system("pause");

return 0;
```

The area marked “Problem here” is where the problem is currently occurring. In stead of prompting for the class description it will skip straight to entering class hours and completely ignore the enter class grade at the bottom.

It prints it as: Enter Class DescriptionEnter Class Hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are trying to teach you the difference between [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). And they are probably tricking you by telling you that the Class ID has to be 4 characters.

So if your Class ID is "1234" and you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after, what ends up in `stdin` is:

`1234\r\n`

The `%5s` format in `scanf` says to read 5 characters and then move on. So, you read in `1234\r` and leave `\n` in the `stdin` stream. Then when `fgets` executes, it reads in the `\n` and moves on.

From the above on `fgets`:

> **Get string from stream**
>
> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline left in the input buffer, from the previous input operation. One way to get rid of it is to read character by character until you've read a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not consume the newline characters by your `scanf` calls. As `fgets` returns when it reads a newline character, it returns immediatelly.

You could change the `scanf` format string to consume newline characters as follow

```
scanf("%5s\r\n", cid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are running this on windows. Windows has issues with flushing its stdin properly. Try using an

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

after any reads from the console.

Comment: I've placed an fflush(stdin); after where I input my class Id and it allows me to input my class description(finally!!), but once I get down to entering my class grade, it immediately prints all of my variables assigned to print, without ever getting the chance to input the class grade